# Верность изложения

Tags: стилистика

Добрый день. Хотелось бы знать насколько правильно написано следующее.

> Цена 1 изделия снижена на 4.8%. Это максимально лояльные условия которые можем принять адекватно Вашим требованиям.

Answer (score 1):

Ну во-первых, запятая нужна перед "которыми".
А во-вторых, что это за "лояльные" и "адекватно"? 
Нельзя по-русски сказать? *"Это всё, на что мы можем пойти, исходя их Ваших требований"?*
Поверьте, канцелярит - совсем не признак крутости. Тем более когда и слова-то используются в довольно странном значении.

*ЛОЯЛЬНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -лен, -льна, -льно. [франц. loyal]
1.
Хранящий верность существующей государственной власти, существующему порядку. Л-ые к власти генералы. Л. специалист. //
Свидетельствующий о такой верности. Л. поступок. Л-ое поведение.
2.
Корректно относящийся к кому-, чему-л. Лоялен по отношению к бригадиру. //
Основанный на корректном отношении к кому-, чему-л. Л-ые отношения. < Лояльно, нареч. Вести себя л.
Лояльность, -и; ж. Проявить л. Л. к власти.*

*АДЕКВАТНЫЙ [дэ], -ая, -ое; -тен, -тна, -тно. [от лат. adaequatus - приравненный]. Книжн.
Вполне соответствующий чему-л. (условиям, обстановке и т.п.);
верный, совпадающий с ожидаемым. А-ые реакции. А-ое лечение 
(соответствующее болезни, точное лечение). А. ребёнок
(о ребёнке с верными реакциями, понятиями). < Адекватность, -и; ж. Адекватно, нареч.*

Разве это то, что вы хотили сказать?

Comment: Ой, благодарю! Буду пользоваться этим ресурсом регулярно.)))